# Why does finally block error out?

Tags: julia

From the `finally` section here: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/control-flow/#finally-clauses, they are using this example:

```
f = open("file")
try
    # operate on file f
finally
    close(f)
end
```

When I run similar code in REPL, this happens:

```
julia> f = open("myfile.txt")
IOStream(<file myfile.txt>)

julia> try
       sqrt(-10)
       finally 
         close(f)
       end
ERROR: DomainError:
 [inlined code] from none:2
 in anonymous at no file:0
```

Any idea what's the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`finally` does not `catch` exceptions. It's for guaranteeing that cleanup steps happen regardless of whether an exception occurred or not. Note the difference between:

```
try
    sqrt(-10)
catch
    println("Exception swallowed!")
end
```

and

```
try
    sqrt(-10)
finally
    println("This cleanup happened regardless of whether an exception was thrown.")
end
```

Often one combines `catch` and `finally`:

```
try
    sqrt(-10)
catch
    println("Swallowed exception.")
finally
    println("...but finally ran regardless.")
end
```

Comment: So why do I get the error? I guess it is misleading since it looks like it has something to do with the file that was opened but is actually about sqrt(-1)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. `sqrt(-1)` is a `DomainError` because `sqrt` returns a `Float64`. The code would work fine if it were `sqrt(-1+0im)`.

Answer (score 1):

`finally` has still done it's job here in the sense that the `close()` operation has been carried out.  You can check this in your code by adding `isopen(f)` which returns false.  You get the error though because you tried to do something that produced it.

Answer (score 0):

`try` block is always followed by the `catch` block. in your program you forget to put catch block before `finally` block.

Comment: While `try` block is usually followed by the `catch` block, it is not true that this is always the case. Sometimes, as in the documentation, you want the error to propagate... but the file to be closed regardless.